# How to set up object material as from camera view

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to set an object material as camera view. Is there any way in Blender to do this?

I don't have any idea so.

btw, I'm using Cycles render engine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting to texture to a camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46746/setting-to-texture-to-a-camera)